# LibGDX: Does the AssetManager have a limit?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Quick question, is there a limit to the number of assets the `AssetManager` can load in libgdx? The best way to ask my question is just to show you what I currently have:

So I am loading in a bunch of my assets on a splash screen before my game starts as shown below:

```
    load();
    while(!assetManager.update())
    {
        System.out.println(assetManager.getProgress() * 100 + "%");
    }
```

The **issue** is that it is getting through 98% of the update process and then never finishing, freezing the splash screen. My first thought was that the last thing it tries to load had some kind of an issue. This is not the case because if I remove just one of the assets being loaded (does not matter which asset) it starts working again. This makes me thinks that my AssetManager has hit some limit and no longer can load assets? These assets are not very large and my emulator shows no issues with memory. I am sure I am missing something stupid, I would really apprectiate some help! Thank you!

This is my load method that simply adds all my assets to the `AssetManger` to get loaded.

```
private void load() {

    assetManager.load("data/backgrounds/mainMenu.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("data/backgrounds/marketStall.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/mainMenuMusic.mp3", Music.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/character.mp3", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/backPack.wav", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/book.wav", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/button.wav", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/coin.wav", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/sounds/sword.wav", Sound.class);
    assetManager.load("data/fonts/black.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
    assetManager.load("data/fonts/blackBigger.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
    assetManager.load("data/fonts/blackEvenBigger.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
    assetManager.load("data/ui/buttons/buttonMainMenu.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.load("data/ui/menuSkin.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/buttonMainMenu.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/settings.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/settingsPack.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/adventureHub.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/adventureHubPack.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/assign.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/assignPack.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/inventory.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/inventory.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/characters.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/characters.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/itemPictures.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/itemPictures.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/adventure.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/adventure.pack"));
    assetManager.load("data/ui/shop.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("data/ui/buttons/shop.pack"));
    }
```

Comment: if you load more assets then where it went up to 98%, will it then stand by <98% or again at 98%?

Comment: @Morchul Interesting, before it was stopping at 98.48484% now it is freezing at 98.55072%.

Comment: So I don't think the AssetManager has a limit, the issue must be somewhere else. Maybe in the AssetManager maybe not but they have no limit. What if you use two AssetManager to load your assets?